# Using Codeigniter with Modular Extensions and Smarty

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine, smarty

I am working on Jasonayre bravenewignition system and want to add this project Smarty. What can i do for using a HMVC system and Smarty together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i did it just some days ago, that's the step for integrating smarty system.

1. Download Smarty from http://www.smarty.net/download
2. Put the smarty folder inside application/third_party
3. Create smarty.php file in application/libraries and paste this

   ```
   require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');

   class CI_Smarty extends Smarty {

   protected $CI;
   private $module;

   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();

       // get CI istance
       $this->CI =& get_instance();
       // fetch the calling module, need to check for views inside it
       $this->module = $this->CI->router->fetch_module();

       // path
       $this->setCompileDir(APPPATH . "cache/smarty/compiled");
       $this->setCacheDir(APPPATH . "cache/smarty/cached");
       $this->setTemplateDir(APPPATH . "views/templates");

       // to use $this inside our views/template
       $this->assignByRef('this', $this->CI);

       log_message('debug', "Smarty Class Initialized");
   }

   public function display ($template, $cache_id = null, $compile_id = null, $parent = null) {
       // automatically add .tpl extension if there is not in $template
       if (strpos($template,'.') === FALSE) {
           $template .= '.tpl';
       }
       if ( !empty($this->module)){
           $template = APPPATH . 'modules/' . $this->module . '/views/' . $template;
       }
       // call the original smarty function
       parent::display($template, $cache_id, $compile_id, $parent);
   }
   }

   /* End of file Smarty.php */
   /* Location: ./application/libraries/Smarty.php */
   ```

ps: sorry for indentation

Now you can use smarty with $this->load->library('smarty') or automatically load it adding smarty to $autoload in the configuration file.

Hope this help! ^^